# Apply a condition to a group and populate only some rows of a new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe grouped by WeekStartDt and WeekEndDt (week excludes Saturday and Sunday). The dataframe is sorted in descending order of `Amount` for each week group. I ranked each group week by `Row_Num` column. The date in the `BusDt` column is the one the highest Amount should be assigned against the 'Transaction Date'. The second highest amount should be assigned to `BusDt + 1`. The `Amount` corresponding to the other `Transaction Dates` should be changed to 0.

I tried using the transform function with max to do this but that added the highest Amount to all the rows. I am not sure how to use a conditional transform here. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

### Input Dataframe

```
| Row_Num | Amount | Transaction Date | WeekStartDt | WeekEndDt  | BusDt   |
|---------|--------|------------------|-------------|------------|---------|
| 1       | 349282 | 2020-02-21       | 2020-02-17  | 2020-02-21 | 2/19/20 |
| 2       | 15440  | 2020-02-18       | 2020-02-17  | 2020-02-21 | 2/19/20 |
| 3       | 6636   | 2020-02-19       | 2020-02-17  | 2020-02-21 | 2/19/20 |
| 4       | 6624   | 2020-02-17       | 2020-02-17  | 2020-02-21 | 2/19/20 |
| 5       | -1526  | 2020-02-20       | 2020-02-17  | 2020-02-21 | 2/19/20 |
| 1       | 502387 | 2020-02-26       | 2020-02-24  | 2020-02-28 | NaT     |
| 2       | 27637  | 2020-02-27       | 2020-02-24  | 2020-02-28 | NaT     |
| 3       | 9736   | 2020-02-24       | 2020-02-24  | 2020-02-28 | NaT     |
| 4       | 6671   | 2020-02-28       | 2020-02-24  | 2020-02-28 | NaT     |
| 5       | 5807   | 2020-02-25       | 2020-02-24  | 2020-02-28 | NaT     |
| 1       | 238532 | 2020-03-06       | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-06 | 3/4/20  |
| 2       | 21399  | 2020-03-05       | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-06 | 3/4/20  |
| 3       | 5837   | 2020-03-02       | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-06 | 3/4/20  |
| 4       | 5683   | 2020-03-04       | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-06 | 3/4/20  |
| 5       | 5670   | 2020-03-03       | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-06 | 3/4/20  |
| 1       | 740786 | 2020-03-12       | 2020-03-09  | 2020-03-13 | NaT     |
| 2       | 71530  | 2020-03-13       | 2020-03-09  | 2020-03-13 | NaT     |
| 3       | 6713   | 2020-03-09       | 2020-03-09  | 2020-03-13 | NaT     |
| 4       | 5648   | 2020-03-10       | 2020-03-09  | 2020-03-13 | NaT     |
| 5       | 5571   | 2020-03-11       | 2020-03-09  | 2020-03-13 | NaT     |
```

### Required Output

```
| Row_Num | Amount | Transaction Date | WeekStartDt | WeekEndDt  | BusDt      | NewAmt |
|---------|--------|------------------|-------------|------------|------------|--------|
| 1       | 349282 | 2020-02-17       | 2020-02-17  | 2020-02-21 | 2020-02-19 | 0      |
| 2       | 15440  | 2020-02-18       | 2020-02-17  | 2020-02-21 | 2020-02-19 | 0      |
| 3       | 6636   | 2020-02-19       | 2020-02-17  | 2020-02-21 | 2020-02-19 | 349282 |
| 4       | 6624   | 2020-02-20       | 2020-02-17  | 2020-02-21 | 2020-02-19 | 15440  |
| 5       | -1526  | 2020-02-21       | 2020-02-17  | 2020-02-21 | 2020-02-19 | 0      |
| 1       | 502387 | 2020-02-24       | 2020-02-24  | 2020-02-28 | NaT        | 0      |
| 2       | 27637  | 2020-02-25       | 2020-02-24  | 2020-02-28 | NaT        | 0      |
| 3       | 9736   | 2020-02-26       | 2020-02-24  | 2020-02-28 | NaT        | 0      |
| 4       | 6671   | 2020-02-27       | 2020-02-24  | 2020-02-28 | NaT        | 0      |
| 5       | 5807   | 2020-02-28       | 2020-02-24  | 2020-02-28 | NaT        | 0      |
| 1       | 238532 | 2020-03-02       | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-06 | 2020-03-04 | 0      |
| 2       | 21399  | 2020-03-03       | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-06 | 2020-03-04 | 0      |
| 3       | 5837   | 2020-03-04       | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-06 | 2020-03-04 | 238532 |
| 4       | 5683   | 2020-03-05       | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-06 | 2020-03-04 | 21399  |
| 5       | 5670   | 2020-03-06       | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-06 | 2020-03-04 | 0      |
| 1       | 740786 | 2020-03-09       | 2020-03-09  | 2020-03-13 | NaT        | 0      |
| 2       | 71530  | 2020-03-10       | 2020-03-09  | 2020-03-13 | NaT        | 0      |
| 3       | 6713   | 2020-03-11       | 2020-03-09  | 2020-03-13 | NaT        | 0      |
| 4       | 5648   | 2020-03-12       | 2020-03-09  | 2020-03-13 | NaT        | 0      |
| 5       | 5571   | 2020-03-13       | 2020-03-09  | 2020-03-13 | NaT        | 0      |
```

```py
df_grouped['NewAmt'] = df_grouped.groupby(['WeekStartDt', 'WeekEndDt'])['Amount'].transform('max')
```

```
| Row_Num | Amount | Transaction Date | WeekStartDt | WeekEndDt  | BusDt      | NewAmt |
|---------|--------|------------------|-------------|------------|------------|--------|
| 1       | 349282 | 2020-02-17       | 2020-02-17  | 2020-02-21 | 2020-02-19 | 349282 |
| 2       | 15440  | 2020-02-18       | 2020-02-17  | 2020-02-21 | 2020-02-19 | 349282 |
| 3       | 6636   | 2020-02-19       | 2020-02-17  | 2020-02-21 | 2020-02-19 | 349282 |
| 4       | 6624   | 2020-02-20       | 2020-02-17  | 2020-02-21 | 2020-02-19 | 349282 |
| 5       | -1526  | 2020-02-21       | 2020-02-17  | 2020-02-21 | 2020-02-19 | 349282 |
| 1       | 502387 | 2020-02-24       | 2020-02-24  | 2020-02-28 | NaT        | 502387 |
| 2       | 27637  | 2020-02-25       | 2020-02-24  | 2020-02-28 | NaT        | 502387 |
| 3       | 9736   | 2020-02-26       | 2020-02-24  | 2020-02-28 | NaT        | 502387 |
| 4       | 6671   | 2020-02-27       | 2020-02-24  | 2020-02-28 | NaT        | 502387 |
| 5       | 5807   | 2020-02-28       | 2020-02-24  | 2020-02-28 | NaT        | 502387 |
| 1       | 238532 | 2020-03-02       | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-06 | 2020-03-04 | 238532 |
| 2       | 21399  | 2020-03-03       | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-06 | 2020-03-04 | 238532 |
| 3       | 5837   | 2020-03-04       | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-06 | 2020-03-04 | 238532 |
| 4       | 5683   | 2020-03-05       | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-06 | 2020-03-04 | 238532 |
| 5       | 5670   | 2020-03-06       | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-06 | 2020-03-04 | 238532 |
| 1       | 740786 | 2020-03-09       | 2020-03-09  | 2020-03-13 | NaT        | 740786 |
| 2       | 71530  | 2020-03-10       | 2020-03-09  | 2020-03-13 | NaT        | 740786 |
| 3       | 6713   | 2020-03-11       | 2020-03-09  | 2020-03-13 | NaT        | 740786 |
| 4       | 5648   | 2020-03-12       | 2020-03-09  | 2020-03-13 | NaT        | 740786 |
| 5       | 5571   | 2020-03-13       | 2020-03-09  | 2020-03-13 | NaT        | 740786 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one `transform` for largest values and another for second largest values. Passing them to `np.select`

```
m = df.TransactionDate == df.BusDt
m1 = m.groupby([df.WeekStartDt, df.WeekEndDt]).shift(fill_value=False)
grps = df.groupby(['WeekStartDt', 'WeekEndDt'])
s_1st = grps['Amount'].transform('max')
s_2nd = grps['Amount'].transform(lambda x: x.nlargest(2).iloc[-1])
df['NewAmt'] = np.select([m, m1], [s_1st, s_2nd], 0)

Out[1510]:
    Row_Num  Amount TransactionDate WeekStartDt   WeekEndDt       BusDt  NewAmt
0         1  349282      2020-02-17  2020-02-17  2020-02-21  2020-02-19       0
1         2   15440      2020-02-18  2020-02-17  2020-02-21  2020-02-19       0
2         3    6636      2020-02-19  2020-02-17  2020-02-21  2020-02-19  349282
3         4    6624      2020-02-20  2020-02-17  2020-02-21  2020-02-19   15440
4         5   -1526      2020-02-21  2020-02-17  2020-02-21  2020-02-19       0
5         1  502387      2020-02-24  2020-02-24  2020-02-28         NaT       0
6         2   27637      2020-02-25  2020-02-24  2020-02-28         NaT       0
7         3    9736      2020-02-26  2020-02-24  2020-02-28         NaT       0
8         4    6671      2020-02-27  2020-02-24  2020-02-28         NaT       0
9         5    5807      2020-02-28  2020-02-24  2020-02-28         NaT       0
10        1  238532      2020-03-02  2020-03-02  2020-03-06  2020-03-04       0
11        2   21399      2020-03-03  2020-03-02  2020-03-06  2020-03-04       0
12        3    5837      2020-03-04  2020-03-02  2020-03-06  2020-03-04  238532
13        4    5683      2020-03-05  2020-03-02  2020-03-06  2020-03-04   21399
14        5    5670      2020-03-06  2020-03-02  2020-03-06  2020-03-04       0
15        1  740786      2020-03-09  2020-03-09  2020-03-13         NaT       0
16        2   71530      2020-03-10  2020-03-09  2020-03-13         NaT       0
17        3    6713      2020-03-11  2020-03-09  2020-03-13         NaT       0
18        4    5648      2020-03-12  2020-03-09  2020-03-13         NaT       0
19        5    5571      2020-03-13  2020-03-09  2020-03-13         NaT       0
```

Answer (score 0):

I used groupby and transform, and two auxiliary variables

```
records = [{'Row_Num': 1,
  'Amount': 349282,
  'Transaction_Date': ' 2020-02-17       ',
  'WeekStartDt': ' 2020-02-17  ',
  'WeekEndDt': ' 2020-02-21 ',
  'BusDt': ' 2020-02-19 '},
 {'Row_Num': 2,
  'Amount': 15440,
  'Transaction_Date': ' 2020-02-18       ',
  'WeekStartDt': ' 2020-02-17  ',
  'WeekEndDt': ' 2020-02-21 ',
  'BusDt': ' 2020-02-19 '},
 {'Row_Num': 3,
  'Amount': 6636,
  'Transaction_Date': ' 2020-02-19       ',
  'WeekStartDt': ' 2020-02-17  ',
  'WeekEndDt': ' 2020-02-21 ',
  'BusDt': ' 2020-02-19 '},
 {'Row_Num': 4,
  'Amount': 6624,
  'Transaction_Date': ' 2020-02-20       ',
  'WeekStartDt': ' 2020-02-17  ',
  'WeekEndDt': ' 2020-02-21 ',
  'BusDt': ' 2020-02-19 '},
 {'Row_Num': 5,
  'Amount': -1526,
  'Transaction_Date': ' 2020-02-21       ',
  'WeekStartDt': ' 2020-02-17  ',
  'WeekEndDt': ' 2020-02-21 ',
  'BusDt': ' 2020-02-19 '},
 {'Row_Num': 1,
  'Amount': 502387,
  'Transaction_Date': ' 2020-02-24       ',
  'WeekStartDt': ' 2020-02-24  ',
  'WeekEndDt': ' 2020-02-28 ',
  'BusDt': ' NaT        '},
 {'Row_Num': 2,
  'Amount': 27637,
  'Transaction_Date': ' 2020-02-25       ',
  'WeekStartDt': ' 2020-02-24  ',
  'WeekEndDt': ' 2020-02-28 ',
  'BusDt': ' NaT        '},
 {'Row_Num': 3,
  'Amount': 9736,
  'Transaction_Date': ' 2020-02-26       ',
  'WeekStartDt': ' 2020-02-24  ',
  'WeekEndDt': ' 2020-02-28 ',
  'BusDt': ' NaT        '},
 {'Row_Num': 4,
  'Amount': 6671,
  'Transaction_Date': ' 2020-02-27       ',
  'WeekStartDt': ' 2020-02-24  ',
  'WeekEndDt': ' 2020-02-28 ',
  'BusDt': ' NaT        '},
 {'Row_Num': 5,
  'Amount': 5807,
  'Transaction_Date': ' 2020-02-28       ',
  'WeekStartDt': ' 2020-02-24  ',
  'WeekEndDt': ' 2020-02-28 ',
  'BusDt': ' NaT        '},
 {'Row_Num': 1,
  'Amount': 238532,
  'Transaction_Date': ' 2020-03-02       ',
  'WeekStartDt': ' 2020-03-02  ',
  'WeekEndDt': ' 2020-03-06 ',
  'BusDt': ' 2020-03-04 '},
 {'Row_Num': 2,
  'Amount': 21399,
  'Transaction_Date': ' 2020-03-03       ',
  'WeekStartDt': ' 2020-03-02  ',
  'WeekEndDt': ' 2020-03-06 ',
  'BusDt': ' 2020-03-04 '},
 {'Row_Num': 3,
  'Amount': 5837,
  'Transaction_Date': ' 2020-03-04       ',
  'WeekStartDt': ' 2020-03-02  ',
  'WeekEndDt': ' 2020-03-06 ',
  'BusDt': ' 2020-03-04 '},
 {'Row_Num': 4,
  'Amount': 5683,
  'Transaction_Date': ' 2020-03-05       ',
  'WeekStartDt': ' 2020-03-02  ',
  'WeekEndDt': ' 2020-03-06 ',
  'BusDt': ' 2020-03-04 '},
 {'Row_Num': 5,
  'Amount': 5670,
  'Transaction_Date': ' 2020-03-06       ',
  'WeekStartDt': ' 2020-03-02  ',
  'WeekEndDt': ' 2020-03-06 ',
  'BusDt': ' 2020-03-04 '},
 {'Row_Num': 1,
  'Amount': 740786,
  'Transaction_Date': ' 2020-03-09       ',
  'WeekStartDt': ' 2020-03-09  ',
  'WeekEndDt': ' 2020-03-13 ',
  'BusDt': ' NaT        '},
 {'Row_Num': 2,
  'Amount': 71530,
  'Transaction_Date': ' 2020-03-10       ',
  'WeekStartDt': ' 2020-03-09  ',
  'WeekEndDt': ' 2020-03-13 ',
  'BusDt': ' NaT        '},
 {'Row_Num': 3,
  'Amount': 6713,
  'Transaction_Date': ' 2020-03-11       ',
  'WeekStartDt': ' 2020-03-09  ',
  'WeekEndDt': ' 2020-03-13 ',
  'BusDt': ' NaT        '},
 {'Row_Num': 4,
  'Amount': 5648,
  'Transaction_Date': ' 2020-03-12       ',
  'WeekStartDt': ' 2020-03-09  ',
  'WeekEndDt': ' 2020-03-13 ',
  'BusDt': ' NaT        '},
 {'Row_Num': 5,
  'Amount': 5571,
  'Transaction_Date': ' 2020-03-13       ',
  'WeekStartDt': ' 2020-03-09  ',
  'WeekEndDt': ' 2020-03-13 ',
  'BusDt': ' NaT        '}]

df = pd.DataFrame(records)
df[['Transaction_Date', 'WeekStartDt', 'WeekEndDt', 'BusDt']] = df[['Transaction_Date', 'WeekStartDt', 'WeekEndDt', 'BusDt']].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
df['NewAmt1'] = df['BusDt'].eq(df['Transaction_Date']) * df.groupby('WeekEndDt')['Amount'].transform(max)
df['NewAmt2'] = df['BusDt'].add(pd.Timedelta(days=1)).eq(df['Transaction_Date']) * df.groupby('WeekEndDt')['Amount'].transform(lambda x: x.nlargest(2).iloc[1])
df['NewAmt'] = df[['NewAmt1', 'NewAmt2']].sum(axis=1)
df
```

Comment: This solution works but need NaT in the output. But Nice Job!!

Comment: You can separate missing and non-missing observations, make the operation over non-missing, and finally join (append) again in one DataFrame

Comment: Even easier, only change `df.groupby('BusDt')` by `df.groupby('WeekEndDt')`
And delete the line with `df.dropna()`
This wok also for NaT values. If this work for you I'll edit the original answer.

Comment: Actually this solution breaks if the `BusDt` is a Friday. Notice all the `TransactionDate` values are weekdays

Comment: Yes,  must be `.groupby(['WeekStartDt', 'WeekEndDt'])`